# How to create Signature Certificate and what i need to mentioned in SP Issuer for okta single logout

Tags: saml, okta, okta-api, saml-2.0

How to configure okta developers application for single log out

```
 Single Logout URL
 SP Issuer
 Signature Certificate
```

Any one please help me how to configure it . how to generate Signature Certificate and sp issuer???

Answer (score 0):

Useing "SIGN ON" Tab(in Okta application) you will get this  details.[image]

using "View Setup intruction" button you can fetch this details. This link provides following attributes:

1. Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL:
2. Identity Provider Issuer:
3. metadata to your SP provider:
4. X.509 Certificate:

If you are using Rails you can use [Omnioth-saml](https://github.com/PracticallyGreen/omniauth-saml) gem

For issuer field you can reffer [this](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/models/account.rb#L15)

References:

1. https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example
2. http://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/setting_up_a_saml_application_in_okta.html

Comment: hey i am able to  implement sso (single sign on) i m trying to implement slo(single log out) using ruby-saml gem and i went through ruby-saml-example But  I am not able to configure my  settings.idp_slo_target_url    i want to know while creating single log out in okta developes as admin, what i need to mention at sp issuer and certificate.. and how to generate that certificate... so that i can generate single logout option